# Visual Studio launch terminal instead of command prompt

Tags: visual-studio, console-application, command-prompt, windows-terminal

I have installed the new [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) and use it for everything instead of the default Command Prompt. However, when I launch a new console application from Visual Studio, it still launches the old Command Prompt.

How can I configure Visual Studio to launch my console application in the new Windows Terminal, instead of the Command Prompt window?

Answer (score 3):

**In Windows 11:**

You have to set Windows Terminal as your default terminal, to do so go to Windows' `Settings>Privacy & Security>For Developers>Terminal` and select Windows Terminal instead of Windows console Host.