# How to make Visual Studio 2022 project launch Windows Terminal instead of PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio, .net-core

I am running Windows 11 and have set Windows Terminal as my default terminal both in the `Settings>Privacy & Security>For Developers>Terminal` applet (per this question: [Visual Studio launch terminal instead of command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211882/visual-studio-launch-terminal-instead-of-command-prompt)), *and* in Visual Studio 2022's Options>Environment>Terminal`. page:

[image]

And yet, when I debug a .Net 8 Minimal Api project, it still launches the regular PowerShell command prompt.

Thsi happens *even after* closing all my terminals and restarting Visual Studio.

The linked question was marked as answered, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think the terminal in the VS settings refers to the immediate mode window in the IDE.  When I started a console mode program from Visual Studio, it appeared in a vsdebugconsole.exe, which seems to be a tailored version of the regular console you'd get with cmd.exe.  After I changed to use Windows Terminal in the Windows settings per the linked question, console programs launched from Visual Studio now appear in a new Windows Terminal window.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy thanks for your response; did you need to restart your machine for the change to take effect?

Comment: I did not restart the machine nor did I log in and out.  I did restart Visual Studio, but I'm not sure whether that was necessary.  Also, I'm still on Windows 10.